# Task on inner functions in Python

Tags: python

I just created my 3 functions for a business problem : wether invest or not in my company.
These are the function i created.
The order should be:
Outer function = def is_investable
inner functions = def sanityChekc, def grahamNumberCalculator
In the end, the result should be "True" for the function is_investable if we decide to invest and false if we decide not.

```
def grahamNumberCalculator(EarningsPerShare, BookValuePerShare):
    ConstInt = 22.5
    IntermediateValue = ConstInt * EarningsPerShare * BookValuePerShare
    HighestPrice = math.sqrt(IntermediateValue)
    return HighestPrice
```

```
def is_investable(MarketPrice, HighestPrice, sanityCheck):
    if MarketPrice <= HighestPrice and sanityCheck == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

```
def sanityCheck(CurrAssets, Liabilities, Debt, EarningOverTime):
    First_subcheck = []
    Second_subcheck = []
    Forth_subcheck = []
    if CurrAssets >= 1.5 * Liabilities:
        First_subcheck.append('True')

    if (Debt / CurrAssets) < 1.1:
        Second_subcheck.append('True')

    for i in EarningOverTime:
        if i > 0:
            Forth_subcheck.append('True')

    if First_subcheck == ['True'] and Second_subcheck == ['True'] and len(Forth_subcheck) == len(EarningOverTime):
        return (True)
    else:
        return (False)
```

This is my first time i try the inner functions, I saw some tutorials and with simple tasks I think i can menage it, but with this i can't figure it out. Would someone help meto understand how it works? Thank you very much

Sorry about the probable confusion of the request

Comment: The fact that you acknowledge your question is probably confusing calls on you to try wording it a little better to bring out the specific challenge you are having

Comment: Let's try to make it more clear. I need to merge those 3 functions.
The main function is : "is_investable" that take the results of the two other function as argument. 
So the result of "def grahamNumberCalculator" and "def sanityCheck" will be the argument of the "is_investable" function. I hope it is more clear now